# F# Recursive Functions: make list items unique

Tags: list, recursion, f#, tail-recursion

```
let rec isolate (l:'a list) = 
    match l with
    | [] -> []
    | x::xs ->
        if memberof(x,xs)
        then remove (x,l)
        else isolate xs
```

I've already created functions memberof and remove, the only problem is that when line 6 remove(x,l) executes it doesn't continue with isolate(xs) for continued search through the list.

Is there a way to say,

```
if x then f(x) and f(y)
```

?

Comment: Are you trying to implement `List.distinct` with recursion?

Comment: Yeah, I believe that is what I'm trying to write as a recursive function.

Comment: Your issue has been resolved?

Comment: This may be a duplicate of [F# deleting common elements in lists](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35095301/1243762)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using F# immutable lists, the result of `remove` needs to be stored somewhere:

```
let rec isolate (l:'a list) = 
    match l with
    | [] -> []
    | x::xs ->
        if memberof(x,xs)
        then
            let xs = remove (x,l)
            isolate xs
        else isolate xs
```

To answer your more general question:

```
let f _ = ()
let f' z = z

let x = true
let y = 42
let z = 3.141

if x then
    f y
    f' z |> ignore
```

The `ignore` is needed here because in F# there are no statements, just expressions, so you can think of `if x then f' z` as

```
if x then
    f' z
else
    ()
```

and thus the first branch needs to return `()` as well.

Comment: it is (* val isolate : l:'a list -> 'a list when 'a : equality *)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to CaringDev's answer.
You may look at this simple solution.
It is worth note, that it's not a fastest way to do this.

```
let rec isolate (acc : 'a list) (l : 'a list) = 
  match l with
  | [] -> acc
  | head :: tail -> 
    if memberof (head, tail)
    then remove (head, tail) |> isolate (acc @ [head])
    else isolate (acc @ [head]) tail

let recursiveDistinct = isolate []
let uniqValues = recursiveDistinct [ 1; 1; 2; 3] //returns [1;2;3]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let isolate list =
    let rec isolateInner searchList commonlist =
        match searchList with
        | x::xs ->
            if (memberof commonlist x) then
                isolateInner xs commonlist
            else
                let commonlist = (x :: commonlist)
                isolateInner xs commonlist
        | [] -> reverse commonlist
    isolateInner list []
```

This is part of an answer to your larger [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35098970/1243762).

Notice that this does not use `remove`. Since you have to pass over each item in the original list and list are immutable, it is better to create a new list and only add the unique items to the new list, then return the new list.